# add_rewrite_rule not loading correct page nor getting variables

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've trying to get a showreel title and video id into an URL that can then be accessed by the page.

i have the two in the same URL and it either doesn't work or only one comes in. Currently the page isn't being found ? (i am constantly flushing the permalinks)

Url i want to get variables from will look like
directors/test-director/showreel/**showreel-name**/video/**111**/

The site currently sits in a testing folder called *independent_02* but not sure if that affects anything?

here's the code;

```
function wpse13483_init() {

    add_rewrite_rule( 'directors/(.+?)/showreels/([^/]+)?/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&showreel=a', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'directors/(.+?)/showreels/([^/]+)/video/([^/]+)?/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&showreel=c1&video=c2', 'top' );
    // directors is a custom post_type and should go to single-directors.php

    add_rewrite_rule( 'showreels/(.+?)/video/([^/]+)?/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&video=b', 'top' );
    // showreels is a custom post_type and should go to single-showreels.php

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse13483_init' );
```

Any help appreciated!

---

**UPDATES** - this rule is now mostly working and catching the variables. However it is going to archive.php and not directors-single.php?

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'directors/(.+?)/showreels/([^/]*)/video/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?post_type=directors&showreel=$matches[2]&video=$matches[3]', 'top' );
// directors is a custom post_type and should go to single-directors.php
```

i think its to do with the '?post_type=directors' but can't find any reference of what this should be to load single.php

**UPDATE 2**
Looking at Rewrite analyzeri think its missing the post_type variable?
[image: rules]

Comment: your rules are a bit confusing - why are you setting `category_name` in each and not your custom post type? why is `showreel` set to static values?

Comment: I got the code from a previous site i did that re-ordered a category by date & desc asc. What should replace the category_name? I guess I'm asking for general guidance for these rewrites and how to structure the rules...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work!

?**post_type**=directors&**name**=$matches[1] seems to be the key

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'directors/([^/]*)/showreels/([^/]*)/video/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?post_type=directors&name=$matches[1]&showreel=$matches[2]&video=$matches[3]', 'top' );
```

so final code now;

```
function wpse13483_init() {

    add_rewrite_rule( 'directors/([^/]*)/showreels/([^/]*)/video/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?post_type=directors&name=$matches[1]&showreel=$matches[2]&video=$matches[3]', 'top' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse13483_init' );

function wpa52794_query_vars( $vars) {
    $vars[] = 'video';
    $vars[] = 'showreel';

    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa52794_query_vars' );
```

Answer (score 2):

WordPress will strip of query variables that it doesn't understand by default.  So in addition to registering your custom rewrite rules, you *also* have to register your custom query variables.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa52794_query_vars' );
function wpa52794_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'video';
    $vars[] = 'showreel';

    return $vars;
}
```

Just to further complete the answer, you also need to specify the regular query variables WordPress is expecting.  Your original example isn't passing the `post_type` or anything to identify the post (ID, name, slug, etc) as you've already noted in your own comments.  Without this, WordPress doesn't understand how to route the request internally.

Kudos for discovering this with a rewrite analyzer.  That was indeed the missing piece.

Comment: Thanks EAMann - but the page is still not found so can't tell if its now catching the vars.

Comment: Do some debugging ... `global $wp_query; echo(print_r($wp_query));` and see what's actually contained in the query.  You *should* see your variables listed in the `$wp_query->query_vars` array.

Comment: Cheers EAMann - i can see the variables coming through now but its loading archive.php and not single.php... I've a feeling post_type=directors should be something else.

Comment: Are you passing some kind of slug or id to WP's internal query processors? If WP doesn't know what post you're looking for, it will return the archive page for that category by default.

Comment: i thought that would still be happening automatically? Or it will be set here index.php?SOMETHING=VALUE?... but can't find any reference. It makes sense that post_type=directors is bringing up an archive of that post type but ?postname, ?id or ?post_name doesn't work and i end up on the index page.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @EAMann answer I can say that you need to flush rewrite rules.

*@EAMann answer*:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa52794_query_vars' );
function wpa52794_query_vars( $vars) {
    $vars[] = 'video';
    $vars[] = 'showreel';

    return $vars;
}
```

*Flushing rewriting rules*:

```
function myplugin_activation() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook ( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activation' );

function myplugin_deactivation() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_deactivation' );
```

Comment: Hey Eugene - i am constantly flushing the permalinks via the permalinks page. best, Dan.