# add_rewrite_rule works only with one "directory"

Tags: rewrite-rules

This works (Wordpress redirects to the canonical URL of the post with the given slug):

```
add_rewrite_rule('mydir/([^/]+)/?$',   'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

This is not working (404)

```
add_rewrite_rule('mydir/mysubdir/([^/]+)/?$',   'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Why? :)

Comment: if the first one redirects, it's actually *not* working, you're getting a 404 and WordPress is guessing what page you mean to be loading and redirecting you there. is the desired page a child of another page? what happens if you hardcode a `page_id` value in your rule instead?

Comment: With harcoded page_id or pagename it always works; with $matches[1] works but only with pages (maybe because WP is guessing? No idea), it doesn't work with the Custom Post type I'm trying to use.

Comment: THIS seems to work! http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53742/33385

Comment: pagename is the query var for the page post type, for custom post types the query var is the slug you registered the post type under. Have a look at WP_Query in codex for valid query vars you can set.